# Stored procedure not as efficient when running through Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I was doing some SQL profiling as preventative maintenance for my website. I saw a particular stored procedure which had a fair number of reads for what it was doing, 9602 with a duration of about 200 ms. While this isn't always alarming, I was checking to see if I could improve the performance a bit since this particular stored procedure is called a bunch.

The stored procedure is called through Entity Framework, simply with

```
mycontext.MySproc(10)
```

I watch in SQL Server profiler and see

```
EXEC [dbo].[MySproc] @id=10
```

Ok, all looks good. But when I go into SSMS and run the stored procedure with

```
EXEC [dbo].[MySproc] @id=10
```

The number of reads is then 820 with a duration of 15 ms!

What the heck is the difference? It's exactly the same command, and since this is in my local dev environment, I know the database isn't changing between calls, so the result set is always the same. I can run the stored procedure again through Entity Framework and get the same higher numbered results, then run again in SSMS and get the lower number results.

Comment: In SSMS, `ARITHABORT` is `ON` by default, while in an ADO.Net session it's `OFF`. That may change the query plan. Could you try to add `SET ARITHABORT ON` as the first line in the sproc? (Just for analysis, not permanent).

Comment: Which Version of EF do you use?
Might be you have enabled some features on EF and it leads to slowness.
I would suggest you to use dapper instead of EF on your read model.

Comment: See [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS?](https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html).

Comment: @GertArnold It can change the query plan, but it does not in itself usually cause the difference in the plan. It's usually parameter sniffing

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the query, the table and index definitions, and share the two query plans via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Sorry, can't add the query